# Problem starting FTP Site using PowerShell

Tags: iis-7, powershell, powershell-2.0

On Windows 7 I run the following Powershell script to start an FTP Site, however I encounter the following error

> Start-Website : Access is denied.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED)) At
>   C:\MyFolder\StartFTPSite.ps1:5 char:16
>   +         Start-WebSite <<<<  -Name "My LocalFTP Site"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (IIS:\sites\My LocalFTP
>   Site:String) [Start-Website],
>   UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.StartWebsiteCommand

Here is the PowerShell script:

```
Clear-Host  
StartWindowsService -svcDisplayName "Microsoft FTP Service"  
Import-Module WebAdministration  
Start-WebSite -Name "My LocalFTP Site"
```

Comment: How did you do to put the code in a nice gray box like that?

Comment: There is a code formatting button on the toolbar of the WYSIWYG editor (looks like "{}").  But the simple wiki formatting is at least 4 spaces indentation with a blank line before the block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Be default windows 7 will start powershell under restricted access uac account.  right click on the powershell icon and say run as administrator and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I already ran that script as admin. May be FTP Site can not be started by script?